# cannot post comment, rate or select the best answer in superuser.com

Tags: support, firefox

Hi,

I am using firefox. Sometimes suddenly it doesn't respond when I click the buttons to post comment, rate or select the best answer in superuser.com. This happens specially when my firefox has been running for a while with quite a few websites open. Similar thing happens to youtube.com, where video sometimes cannot be played allegedly because of not the latest adobe flash player or not enabling it, but these are not true in my case. Is it because firefox takes up too much memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shift+Reload to force reload of the SO Javascript. If that doesn't work, clear your browser cache.